# Send data from seperate thread within a service to service Class

Tags: android, multithreading, service

Can anyone suggest me a good tutorial which explains on how to send data from android seperate thread class which is within the service class -----> sends data to------> service `oncreate()` method.

The thread can be timertask or thread class or any kind but those all threads are within service class

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood when you say

> data to------> service oncreate()

However, you need to use a [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) created inside service's onCreate method and pass it to the thread. [Posting a runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to the handler from the thread will result in executing the runnable in the ui thread (which is the thread the service is running on).

Comment: I am having a seperate thread class inside service and when I start a thread and sent data from that thread to service onCreate() method it always gives me null.. Can some one provide a clear tutorial on this ? It will be helpful